# Text overlapping on footer (text in a frame)

Tags: header-footer, overlap

I have a problem to which I cannot find a solution: I try to make kind of a corpus of documents with Latex by having each document in a frame.

For small documents there is no problem but for those who are more than one page, the overlaps on the footer. Here is a picture.[image]

The frame is created using the following line: \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{*text here*}

But that does not seem to take into account when the text arrives at the bottom of the page.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why don't you load the `framed`  package and use the eponymous environment? It can break across pages.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wonder why I didn't find it earlier ... Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.